# Maximum update depth exceeded - React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am building a react application in which user enters a search word and backend gives array of json. On the result page I am trying to implement faceted search, so I have few filters. I am filtering the fetched result based on the user chosen checkboxes. Here is the UI.
[image]

This is my js file for the search results page.

```js
import React from 'react';
import NavigationBar from './NavigationBar';
import SearchPageResultsStyle from "../assets/css/SearchResultsPage.css"
import Pagination from './Pagination';

class SearchResultsPage  extends React.Component{
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            results: this.props.location.state.data.results,
            keyword: this.props.location.state.data.keyword,
            pageOfItems: [],
            cities: {
                'New York City (NYC)': false,
                'Delhi': false,
                'Bangkok': false,
                'Paris': false,
                'Mexico City': false
            },
            topics: {
                'Environment': false,
                'Crime': false,
                'Politics': false,
                'Social Unrest': false,
                'Infrastructure': false
            },
            languages: {
                'Hindi': false,
                'English': false,
                'Thai': false,
                'French': false,
                'Spanish': false
            }
        };
        this.onChangePage = this.onChangePage.bind(this);
        this.onCityChange = this.onCityChange.bind(this);
    }

    componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
        if (prevState !== this.state) {
            console.log(this.state.cities);
            const filteredCities = [];
            for (let key in this.state.cities) {
                if (this.state.cities[key] === true) {
                    filteredCities.push(key)
                }
            }
            console.log(filteredCities);
            const filteredResults = [];
            this.state.results.forEach((result) => {
                for (let i = 0; i < filteredCities.length; i++) {
                    if (result.city === filteredCities[i]) {
                        filteredResults.push(result)
                    }
                }
            })
            console.log("fileterdPageOfItems", filteredResults)
            this.updatePageOfItems(filteredResults)

        }
    }

    // Function to filter the search results based on user chosen filters
    updatePageOfItems(filteredResults) {
        this.setState({
            results: filteredResults
        })
    }

    onChangePage(pageOfItems) {
        // update local state with new page of items
        this.setState({pageOfItems});
    }

    // setting each city in cities object (city chechboxes which are clicked on UI) to true
    onCityChange(e) {
        const val = e.target.checked;
        const name = e.target.name;
        let updatedCities = Object.assign({},this.state.cities,{[name]: val});
        this.setState({
            cities: updatedCities,
        })
    }

    // rendering checkboxes for cities
    renderCity() {
        const cities = ['New York City (NYC)','Delhi','Bangkok','Paris','Mexico City']
        return cities.map((city,i) => {
            return (
                <div>
                    <label key={i}>
                        {city}
                        <input
                            type="checkbox"
                            name={city}
                            onChange={this.onCityChange}
                            value={this.state.cities[city]}/>
                    </label>
                </div>

            )
        })
    }

    render() {

        const renderItems = this.state.pageOfItems.map((item, index) => {
            return (
                <div>
                    <h3 style={{color: '#1a0dab'}} key={index}>{item.text}</h3>
                    <a href={'https://google.com'} key={index}>{item.tweetUrl}</a>
                    <br/>
                    <p><span style={{fontWeight:'bold', textColor:'#6a6a6a'}} key={index}>topic: </span>{item.topic}</p>
                    <p><span style={{fontWeight:'bold', textColor:'#6a6a6a'}} key={index}>city: </span>{item.city}</p>
                    <p><span style={{fontWeight:'bold', textColor:'#6a6a6a'}} key={index}>lang: </span>{item.lang}</p>
                    <p><span style={{fontWeight:'bold', textColor:'#6a6a6a'}} key={index}>Hashtags: </span></p>
                    <hr/>
                </div>
            )
        });

        return (
            <div>
                <NavigationBar/>
                <h4 style={{textAlign:'center', color:'#1a0dab'}}>Showing search results for <span style={{fontWeight:'bold', fontStyle:'Italic'}}>'{this.state.keyword}'</span></h4>
                <hr/>
                <div className={'wrap'} style={SearchPageResultsStyle}>
                    <div className={'fleft'}>
                        <h4>City</h4>
                        {this.renderCity()}
                        <hr/>
                        <h4>Topics</h4>
                        <hr/>
                        <h4>Language</h4>
                        <hr/>
                    </div>
                    <div className={'fcenter'}>
                        {renderItems}
                        <Pagination items={this.state.results} onChangePage={this.onChangePage}/>
                    </div>
                    <div className={'fright'}></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }

}

export default SearchResultsPage;
```

I am updating the cities in my state to true whenever a user clicks on a particular checkbox, and then I am filtering the fetched result (from backend) based on the cities in my array `filteredCities` and I am collecting the filtered results in an array `filteredResults`, and then I am passing this array to a function `updatePageOfItems` to change the state so that my filtered result could get re-rendered. But When I am calling the function `updatePageOfItems`, the application is getting into infinite loop.
What is the work around for this problem. I am new to react and facing this issue for the first time.

Here is the stack trace
[image]

Comment: The error already says everything. Inside your `componendDidUpdate` you are changing the state always. `if (prevState !== this.state) ` is always true. This change of state triggers componentDidUpdate, which triggers the change of state, which triggers componentDidUpdate, and so on...

Comment: @quirimmo what check should I apply then, to avoid this...

Comment: I have no idea what is happening here. Yeah I understand that you are doing a search and filtering results, but that's really a mess and over complicated for a simple search. In my personal opinion, start to re design from zero your component logic keeping things as simple as possible.

Comment: IMHO fixing the error you mentioned and then putting this code on code review could help you a lot

Comment: @Treycos where do I put my code for code review, is there a seperate portal or here itself????

Comment: It is another stack exchange subsite, just like SO. But instead you can only post working code that you think could be improved/optimized. The rules are pretty strict but the answers are generally more really worth your time

Comment: @Treycos thanks a lot, will do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve the issue, instead of filtering the results in the function `componentDidUpdate` I did the operation in the callback function of `setState` inside `onCityChange` function.

```js
onCityChange(e) {
        const val = e.target.checked;
        const name = e.target.name;
        let updatedCities = Object.assign({},this.state.cities,{[name]: val});
        this.setState({
            cities: updatedCities,
        },function () {
            const filteredCities = [];
            for (let key in this.state.cities) {
                if (this.state.cities[key] === true) {
                    filteredCities.push(key)
                }
            }
            console.log("filteredCities", filteredCities);
            const filteredResults = [];
            this.state.results.forEach((result) => {
                for (let i = 0; i < filteredCities.length; i++) {
                    if (result.city === filteredCities[i]) {
                        filteredResults.push(result)
                    }
                }
            })
            this.setState({
                results: filteredResults
            },function () {
                console.log(this.state.results)
            })
        })
    }
```